# how to upload file in laravel 5 (doesnt read Form file)

Tags: javascript, php, dom, laravel-5

[image]

hi all I have question about laravel 5
why my laravel cannot read  Form::file('image')..??
this for screenshoot 
This for my code
and for my controller

```html
   {!! Form::open(array('action' =>'AdminPageControllers@submit_hole', 'class'=>'pure-form pure-form-stacked', 'files'=>true)) !!}

{!! Form::file('image') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Using ajax to upload file?

Comment: In the image it is showing on network tab.

Comment: Please show as your controller method `submit_hole`.